# ClassCastException Exception while invoking finish() from AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-context

Please help I am new to android. I have async task which does some network task. after completing it. It should finish the previous activity. So i give context to asyntask and from there i did this

```
((Activity)context).finish();
```

and it give me this exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.ContextImpl cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
```

Is this is wrong approach. If yes then what is the best practice to this.

Comment: Just call `finish()` if you are in `Activity`

Comment: No i was not in activity......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
((YourActivityName)context).finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

> A ClassCastException is thrown by Java when you try to cast an Object
>   of one data type to another .

You can add

```
onBackPressed();
```

> Called when the activity has detected the user's press of the back
>   key.

Or Simply add

```
finish(); // this.finish();
```

Or

```
this.getContext().finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you have coded as mentioned), Instead of passing `Context` Pass the `Activity` object itself to your `AsyncTask`

Doing so you will not need to do the casting.

In your `Activity` you can do

```
Activity mActivity = this;
```

and then pass `mActivity` instead of `context` and directly call `mActivity.finish()` on it.